# How to match the Nth word of a line containing a specific word using regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to do to get the correct regular expression to match the Nth word of a line containing a specific word.

For example, if I have this input:

```
this is the first line - blue
this is the second line - green
this is the third line - red
```

I want to match the seventh word of the lines containing the word "second" and return `green`.

I'm using [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) to test the regular expression.

I already tried out this regular expression without success - it is matching the next line:

```
(.*second.*)(?<data>.*?\s){7}(.*)
```

Another example input:

```
this is the Foo line - blue
this is the Bar line - green
this is the Test line - red
```

I want to match the fourth word of the lines containing the word "red" and return `Test`.

The word I want to match can come either *before* or *after* the word I use to select the line.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use this to match a line containing `second` and grab the 7th word:

```
^(?=.*\bsecond\b)(?:\S+ ){6}(\S+)
```

Make sure that the global and multiline flags are active.

`^` matches the beginning of a line.

`(?=.*\bsecond\b)` is a positive lookahead to make sure there's the word `second` in that particular line.

`(?:\S+ ){6}` matches 6 words.

`(\S+)` will get the 7th.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/fA5iM3)

---

You can apply the same principle with other requirements.

With a line containing `red` and getting the 4th word...

```
^(?=.*\bred\b)(?:\S+ ){3}(\S+)
```

Comment: He only wants to match the 7th word on the line that contains "second", which itself is one of the words on the line.

Comment: @Jerry Thaks, but It doesn't solve my problem - I need the line with the word 'second', not the second line.

Comment: +1, but important to note the "m" flag on the regex.

Comment: @Palpatim Thanks, I made a mess out there >~<

Comment: I like the newer answer better than the old one.

Comment: @Floris I do too. I hate myself when I misread something and realise I did so a bit too late :(

Answer (score 3):

You asked for regex, and you got a very good answer.

Sometimes you need to ask for the solution, and not specify the tool.

Here is the one-liner that I think best suits your need:

```
awk '/second/ {print $7}' < inputFile.txt
```

Explanation:

```
/second/     - for any line that matches this regex (in this case, literal 'second')
print $7     - print the 7th field (by default, fields are separated by space)
```

I think it is much easier to understand than the regex - and it's more flexible for this kind of processing.

Comment: Asking for the tool implies the person asking has already decided what the solution should be, which is what we call an XY-problem. "[What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/153968)" discusses the situation. Usually, whatever ever solution they've predetermined is the way to do it is wrong.

Comment: @theTinMan completely agree with you!