# Non-capturing Group in R Regex

Tags: regex, r, substring, stringr, regex-group

I'm trying to extract the `n`th word from strings and found several [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21485228/regex-match-the-nth-word-of-a-line-containing-a-specific-word) that suggest a method that doesn't seem to work in R.

```
myString <- "HANS CHRISTIAN ANDERSON III"

str_extract(myString,'(?:\\S+ ){1}(\\S+)')
# [1] "HANS CHRISTIAN"
str_extract(myString,'(?:\\S+ ){2}(\\S+)')
# [1] "HANS CHRISTIAN ANDERSON"
```

As you can see, my commands are returning both the non-capturing and capturing group. What's the solution to get only the specific `n`th word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Regex is right. It's because you didn't get the group 1 value, but instead, you turn all the caught string by Regex.

```
library(stringr)

r <- "(?:\\S+ ){1}(\\S+)"
s <- "HANS CHRISTIAN ANDERSON III"

str_match_all(s, r)
#[[1]]
#           [,1]           [,2]  
#[1,] "HANS CHRISTIAN" "CHRISTIAN"
```

Comment: Is there a way to match using regex as opposed to using `str_match(myString,"(?:\\S+ ){1}(\\S+)")[2]`?

Comment: In this answer, I use `str_match_all`. I think you can't get a group value using `str_match`

Answer (score 2):

The negation of character classes is formed when the first character is "^", so this finds all non-space characters and the first space in the first capture class.

```
# second space delimited name
 gsub( '^([^ ]+[ ])([^ ]+)([ ]+.+$)', "\\2", myString)
[1] "CHRISTIAN"
```

Another strategy, arguably less failure prone:

```
# easy to use a numberic value to pick from a scan-read:
 scan(text=myString, what="")[2]
Read 4 items
[1] "CHRISTIAN"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm partial to `strsplit`:

```
strsplit(myString, ' ')[[1]][2]
# [1] "CHRISTIAN"

paste(strsplit(myString, ' ')[[1]][1:2], collapse = ' ')
# [1] "HANS CHRISTIAN"
```

Comment: Indeed, regex can be overkill for this task if the strings are not complex . In vectorised form you'd have: `sapply(strsplit(myString,"\\s+"), \`[\`, 2)` or `vapply(strsplit(myString,"\\s+"), \`[\`, 2, FUN.VALUE=character(1))` if speed matters.