# How to change a word that is neither in the beginning nor in the end using regex?

Tags: regex, vim

So I got something like this:

```
word word word
word word word
word word word
```

And I want this:

```
word changed word 
word changed word
word changed word
```

**EDIT (Solved)**

`%s/ word\(\w\|\s\w\)\@=/ changed/g`

I am sure there is a more concise way to do this and it's not perfect becuase I am taking for granted that there is no space in the begining of the line.
But it works, thank you for your answers I have learned a couple of things

Comment: Possible duplicate of [REGEX - match the Nth word of a line containing a specific word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21485228/regex-match-the-nth-word-of-a-line-containing-a-specific-word)

Answer (score 1):

Use negative look arounds:

```
(?!<^)word(?!$)
```

The matches `word` that is neither preceded by start nor followed by end.

Answer (score 0):

If you have data like:

```
word something else word
word stuff in here word
word other stuff in here word
```

You could use match groups like `(word)(.*?)\1` to match the first word, match everything until you you got to the first word again. then you could use match group 2 to edit that data.

But your question really doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Welcome to SO! If a question doesn't make sense, ask questions in the comments until it does then try to answer. Answering something you don't understand generates noise and doesn't help the OP, especially when you make comments like "But your question really doesn't make any sense." which would have best been pointed out in a clarifying question in a comment. "[answer]" will help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
:%s/ \w\+/ changed
```

It will replace all second-column words (assuming a single space as the column separator). For details of `:g` and `:s` commands refer to `:help :g` and `:help :s`. If the second column contains words of the same length then you could use a blockwise replacement (`<c-v>` = Ctrl+V)

```
gg0w<c-v>Gecchanged<esc>
```

Comment: This isnt different substantially from `:%s/ \w\+/ changed/`

Answer (score 0):

Meh, don’t use regex: use a macro.

```
qq^wciwchanged<Esc>q
```

Then simply play it in your favorite way (`@q`, after which `@@` works; `:%normal! @q`, `:global/pat/normal! @q`, &c.).

How it works:

1. `^` to go to the beginning
2. `w` to go to the next word (you can use `3w` to get to the third word, etc.)
3. `ciwchanged` followed by hitting escape to change the word

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. Anyway I am doing this in order to learn regex and get use to them.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the exact output you suggested with this command:

```
:%norm wcwchanged

% ................. Whole file
norm .............. normal mode
w ................. jump to the second word
cw ................ change word
```